# Produce a symbol from a symbol in a macro

Tags: macros, metaprogramming, julia

I'm not sure how to express this. I have a macro like so:

```
macro dothing(xxxx)
  # create a new symbol
  ZC_xxxx = symbol("ZC_"*string(xxxx))

  # esc so that variables are assigned in calling scope
  return esc(quote
    # assign something to the new symbol
    $ZC_xxxx = [555.0, 666.0, 777.0]

    # Store in a the dataframe
    t[:(:($ZC_xxxx))] = $ZC_xxxx
  end)
end

t = DataFrame()
@dothing(ABCD)
```

I want the macro to do two things: create a new variable in the calling scope, called ZC_ABCD; add a new column to the dataframe with this name and the value of the returned value. i.e. I want the expression returned from the macro to look like this:

```
ZC_ABCD = [555.0, 666.0, 777.0]
t[:ZC_ABCD] = ZC_ABCD
```

With the above show, if I add a call to `show(expr)` before returning it from the macro, it shows this:

```
ZC_ABCD = [555.0, 666.0, 777.0]
t[:ZC_xxxx] = ZC_ABCD
```

i.e. notice that the symbol used in the index lookup in the dataframe is not correct.

How can I achieve the desired result from the macro? What am I not understanding about symbol interpolation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try quoting the symbol before you use it in generating an expression with the symbol:

```
macro dothing(xxxx)
    # create a new symbol
    ZC_xxxx = symbol("ZC_"*string(xxxx))
    q = Expr(:quote, ZC_xxxx)

    # esc so that variables are assigned in calling scope
    return esc(quote
        # assign something to the new symbol
        $ZC_xxxx = [555.0, 666.0, 777.0]

        # Store in a the dataframe
        t[$q] = $ZC_xxxx
    end)
end
```

That said, stylistically this kind of variable manipulation is a little dicey, because it's really hard to guess what `@dothing` does just by looking at the call (it references all sorts of quantities that do not appear in the `@dothing(ABCD)` expression).

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I'm aware that this is a little dicey, but it is for a large amount of code generation and I think this macro will be less trouble than maintaining the identical code for many different variables.

Comment: This was interesting but ultimately you were correct. It is more readable and less brittle as a function where I pass in the table etc